# golng fetching url and resp.Body.Close()

Tags: go

I am looking for go code to fetch url and in most of the cases this the code for fetching url on go :

```
func main() {
    for _, url := range os.Args[1:] {
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "fetch: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "fetch: reading %s: %v\n", url, err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", b)
    }
}
```

my question why needed here resp.Body.Close() and whay this exactly doing ?

Answer (score 2):

If you dig into the http docs https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

The Get method used to make the resp is a Response

```
 func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
```

In the Response source:

```
        // Body represents the response body.
        //
        // The response body is streamed on demand as the Body field
        // is read. If the network connection fails or the server
        // terminates the response, Body.Read calls return an error.
        //
        // The http Client and Transport guarantee that Body is always
        // non-nil, even on responses without a body or responses with
        // a zero-length body. It is the caller's responsibility to
        // close Body. The default HTTP client's Transport may not
        // reuse HTTP/1.x "keep-alive" TCP connections if the Body is
        // not read to completion and closed.
        //
        // The Body is automatically dechunked if the server replied
        // with a "chunked" Transfer-Encoding.
        Body io.ReadCloser
```

So the Close() tidies up the resources that are used to get the Body

If this isn't done the Response (resp) won't be able to do "keep-alive" and I guess there is a chance that some of the resources in the Response won't be able to be recycled

Answer (score 1):

when you use `ioutil.ReadAll` what you are doing is calling the `Read` function of `response.Body`. What this does is set a "seeker" going which reads the contents of the `response.Body` and returns a buffer containing that. When you `Close` the `response.Body` you are resetting this "seeker" position at zero and returns the tcp connection to the connection pool. This ensures that any future reads you may do on this response will start from zero, as opposed to say `EOF` and ensures that there is no un-returned tcp connection waiting to be read.